# Numpy create boolean array from checking if an array index equal a letter

Tags: arrays, numpy, boolean-logic

I have a numpy array of letters `'x'` and `'y'`. How do I make a boolean array for this that returns true if index `== 'x'` and false otherwise?

Comment: In addition to John1024's answer, have a look at the functions in `numpy.char` for vectorized versions of things like `upper`, `isspace`, etc: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.char.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array(['x', 'y', 'y', 'x', 'y'])

In [3]: a == 'x'
Out[3]: array([ True, False, False,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

Answer (score 0):

A more general approach, useful for multiple letter conditions:

```
base_mask = lambda x: x == 'A' or x == 'a' or x == 'T' or x == 't'
vec_base_mask = np.vectorize(base_mask)
seq = 'TCTATcgGGa'
a = np.array([*seq])
masked_a = vec_base_mask(a)

# >>> masked_a
# array([ True, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False, False, False,
#         True])
```